# xlsxwriter set_custom_property to an existing workbook without creating a new one

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

To my understanding, `xlsxwriter` can only create new workbooks, not modify existing ones--or can it? I would like to simply add some custom properties to an already-existing workbook by using the `workbook.set_custom_property()` method.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-set-custom-property

Comment: I found this link in the documentation https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/alternatives.html
You can find another tools that provide update functionalities, for example "OpenPyXL"

Comment: This function doesn't seem to be implemented yet in openpyxl @DavidRodrigues

Comment: May be doable with xlwings, or with win32com.

Comment: @BigBen I can do this with win32com, but it's a lot more error-prone that xlsxwriter and openpyxl. I've asked other questions how how to do this with openpyxl.

Comment: How is win32com more error prone?

Comment: From what I've tried, it opens Excel in the foreground. When I save the Workbook, it prompts for a save name which defeats my automation needs. If I try to pass some args like FileName, I get some path not found errors. If the process is interrupted, I have to kill the Excel process if I want to restart. It's also significantly slower.

Comment: Those all  sound fixable, and not due to win32com itself but rather how you're using it.